# Check if two strings contain the same set of words in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, text, text-extraction

I am trying to compare two sentences and see if they contain the same set of words. 
Eg: comparing "today is a good day" and "is today a good day" should return true
I am using the Counter function from collections module right now

```py
from collections import Counter


vocab = {}
for line in file_ob:
    flag = 0
    for sentence in vocab:
        if Counter(sentence.split(" ")) == Counter(line.split(" ")):
            vocab[sentence]+=1
            flag = 1
            break
        if flag==0:
            vocab[line]=1
```

It seems to work fine for a few lines, but my text file has more than 1000 and it never finishes executing. Is there any other way, something more efficient that would help me compute the result for the entire file?
 
EDIT:

I just need a replacement for the Counter method, something to replace it. And not any change in the implementation.

Comment: Do you need to distinguish duplicate words? Should `to to` match `to to to`?

Comment: If not, turn the list of words into a `set` and test if the two sets are equal.

Comment: Anything else I can use instead of sets?

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want to change the implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really don't need to use two loops.

## Correct way to use dicts

Let's say you have a `dict`:

```
my_dict = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4, 'e': 5, 'f': 5, 'g': 6}
```

Your code is basically equivalent to:

```
for (key, value) in my_dict.items():
    if key == 'c':
        print(value)
        break
#=> 3
```

But the whole point of `dict` (and `set`, `Counter`, ...) is to be able to get the desired value directly:

```
my_dict['c']
#=> 3
```

If your dict has 1000 values, the first example will be 500 times slower than the second, on average. Here's a simple description I've found on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/java/comments/1a5bps/can_someone_explain_to_me_like_im_5_what_a/c8u7td1?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x):

> A dict is like a magic coat check room. You hand your coat over and
>   get a ticket. Whenever you give that ticket back, you immediately get
>   your coat. You can have a lot of coats, but you still get your coat
>   back immediately. There is a lot of magic going on inside the coat
>   check room, but you don't really care as long as you get your coat
>   back immediately.

## Refactored code

You just need to find a common signature between `"Today is a good day!"` and `"Is today a good day?"`. One way would be to extract the words, convert them to lowercase, sort them and join them. What's important is that the output should be immutable (e.g. `tuple`, `string`, `frozenset`). This way, it can be used inside sets, Counters or dicts *directly*, without needing to iterate over every key.

```
from collections import Counter

sentences = ["Today is a good day", 'a b c', 'a a b c', 'c b a', "Is today a good day"]

vocab = Counter()
for sentence in sentences:
    sorted_words = ' '.join(sorted(sentence.lower().split(" ")))
    vocab[sorted_words] += 1

vocab
#=> # Counter({'a day good is today': 2, 'a b c': 2, 'a a b c': 1})
```

or even shorter:

```
from collections import Counter

sentences = ["Today is a good day", 'a b c', 'a a b c', 'c b a', "Is today a good day"]

def sorted_words(sentence):
    return ' '.join(sorted(sentence.lower().split(" ")))

vocab = Counter(sorted_words(sentence) for sentence in sentences)
# Counter({'a day good is today': 2, 'a b c': 2, 'a a b c': 1})
```

This code should be much faster than what you've tried until now.

## Yet another alternative

If you want to keep the original sentences in a list, you can use `setdefault` :

```
sentences = ["Today is a good day", 'a b c', 'a a b c', 'c b a', "Is today a good day"]

def sorted_words(sentence):
    return ' '.join(sorted(sentence.lower().split(" ")))

vocab = {}
for sentence in sentences:
    vocab.setdefault(sorted_words(sentence), []).append(sentence)

vocab

#=> {'a day good is today': ['Today is a good day', 'Is today a good day'],
# 'a b c': ['a b c', 'c b a'],
# 'a a b c': ['a a b c']}
```

Comment: This actually works really fast. But could you elaborate on how I could make the above code faster. Just by changing the counter and use something else. Either user defined or in built function

Comment: I lose the order of words when I create a dictionary with the strings as keys. Yes I am able to get the count of similar sentences but then I lose the original order

Comment: @TheLastCoder: That's why I wrote the "more complex example". Anyway, there's a shorter version in "Yet another alternative".

Comment: I understand how the dictionary works. What I want is to have dictionary keys that are already in the text with the count equal to the number of similar strings(similar means have the same set of words)

Comment: @TheLastCoder: What would a key look like, for example for `"Today is a good day"`?

Comment: yes! and it's values will be 2 since ['Today is a good day', 'Is today a good day'],

Comment: @TheLastCoder: Yes what? What would be the common key for `['Today is a good day', 'Is today a good day']`?

Comment: Anything, maybe the one that comes first

Comment: @TheLastCoder: All the information you need is inside `vocab = {'a day good is today': ['Today is a good day', 'Is today a good day'], 'a b c': ['a b c', 'c b a'], 'a a b c': ['a a b c']}`. If you have a sentence, you just need to call `vocab[sorted_words(sentence)]` to get all the sentences with the same words, or `vocab[sorted_words(sentence)][0]` to get the first one.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like

```
set(sentence.split(" ")) == set(line.split(" "))
```

Comparing **set** objects is faster than comparing **counter**. Both set and counter objects are basically sets, however when you use counter object for comparison, it has to compare both the keys and values whereas the set only has to compare keys. 
Thank you **Eric** and **Barmar** for your inputs.

Your full code will look like

```py
from collections import Counter
vocab = {a dictionary of around 1000 sentences as keys}
for line in file_ob:
    for sentence in vocab:
        if set(sentence.split(" ")) == set(line.split(" ")):
            vocab[sentence]+=1
```

Comment: There's really not much difference between a `set`, a `dict` and a `counter`. A set is basically a dict in which values are ignored. It's much better to use a `O(1)` or `O(n)` solution with counters than `O(n**2)` with sets.

Comment: I am sorry, I phrased the question for simplicity. In my actual code, the vocab is generated within the for loop. Basically I am generating ngrams from a text file and ensuring that no two ngram has the same set of words. Converting them to set actually worked but it's still slow. I was wondering if there was a faster option

Comment: @EricDuminil Is there anything that I can use instead of sets?

Comment: @EricDuminil The counter solution has to compare both the keys and values, the set only has to compare keys. They're both O(n).

Comment: @TheLastCoder: sets and counters are perfectly fine. You just need to find the correct keys and use sets the way they're supposed to be used : not iterating over every key.

Comment: @Barmar: The problem here is the structure of the code and that there's one unneeded loop. It doesn't make any noticeable difference at all if both keys and values are compared, or just the keys. OP's code seems to be at least O(n**2), but could be O(n).

Comment: @Eric I told you, this is not the actual code I am running, I am generating the vocab dictionary withing the loop, so I have to put it inside.  I am really sorry for the confusion. Wait, let me edit the question. By far set has been the fastest implementation

Comment: @Eric Please check the code again. Hope it makes sense. Do ask me if you need any clarification.

Comment: Edited the solution. Thank you for all your inputs.

Comment: Sorry for being blunt, but `Counter` wasn't the problem, and your code isn't the solution either. There simply shouldn't be two `for` loops.

Answer (score 2):

To take duplicate/multiple words into account your equality comparison may be:

```py
def hash_sentence(s):                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    return hash(''.join(sorted(s.split())))                                                                                                                                                                                                                   

a = 'today is a good day'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
b = 'is today a good day'                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
c = 'today is a good day is a good day'                                                                                                                                                                                                                       

hash_sentence(a) == hash_sentence(b)  # True
hash_sentence(a) == hash_sentence(c)  # False
```

Also, note that in your implementation every sentence is counted n-times (`for sentence in vocab:`).

Comment: I phrased the question for simplicity. In my actual code, the vocab is generated within the for loop. Basically I am generating ngrams from a text file and ensuring that no two ngram has the same set of words. Converting them to set actually worked but it's still slow. I was wondering if there was a faster option

Comment: It's probably the way to go. You can then group the sentences by hash and get similar sentences directly.

Comment: This is an elegant solution. Let me use the timeit function and get back to you! let me see if the set function or this implementation is faster

Comment: Time for this implementation : 31.8790001869, now running the plain old set implementation

Comment: time taken using sets :  15.1610000134

Comment: that is interesting... try to tuple the sorted sequence instead of joining to a string if you would...

Comment: actually, depending on your input data, you may be able to even omit the `.split()` and just sort the string directly -- for the purpose of hashing that is.

Comment: Its just plain text file with over 1000 lines of random text. Yeah, I can try that

Comment: Well it certainly performed faster than using join. time taken  26.7250001431 still slower than sets :/

Comment: Out of despair a last one: `sum(hash(x) for x in s.split())`, else: built-ins for the win!!!

Comment: @TheLastCoder: Could you please check https://stackoverflow.com/a/56761941/6419007 and see if it works for you ? Load all your file with `sentences = file_ob.readlines()` and run the code. I think it should complete in a few ms.

Comment: @MarkusRother: Don't despair yet. Your code and idea are fine. I really think it's the way OP uses them that's the problem here.

Comment: @MarkusRother: time taken  41.7990000248 :/

Comment: @TheLastCoder wait, let me try it. Sorry for not responding.

Comment: I am just going with sets. @MarkusRother, I have saved your code for referencing in the future.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, you can extract the Counter construction outside of the inner loop, instead of recalculating each for every pair - this should improve the algorithm by a factor proportional to the avg # of tokens per string.

```
from collections import Counter
vocab = {a dictionary of around 1000 sentences as keys}

vocab_counter = {k: Counter(k.split(" ")) for k in vocab.keys() }

for line in file_obj:
    line_counter = Counter(line.split(" "))
    for sentence in vocab:
        if vocab_counter[sentence] == line_counter:
            vocab[sentence]+=1
```

Further improvements could be had by using the Counters as indices to a dictionary, which would let you replace the linear search for matching sentences with a lookup. The `frozendict` package would probably be useful so that you can use a dictionary as a key to another dictionary.

Comment: I am sorry, I phrased the question for simplicity. In my actual code, the vocab is generated within the for loop. Basically I am generating ngrams from a text file and ensuring that no two ngram has the same set of words. Converting them to set actually worked but it's still slow. I was wondering if there was a faster option